# How to access app once deployed via Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a very simple Python app that works fine when I execute `uvicorn main:app --reload`. When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` on my machine, I'm able to interact with the API. (My app has no frontend, it is just an API built with FastAPI). However, I am trying to deploy this via Kubernetes, but am not sure how I can access/interact with my API.

Here is my `deployment.yaml`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec: 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When I enter `kubectl describe deployments my-deployment` in the terminal, I get back a print out of the deployment, the namespace it is in, the pod template, a list of events, etc. So, I am pretty sure it is properly deployed.

How can I access the application? What would the url be? I have tried a variety of localhost  + port combinations to no avail. I am new to kubernetes so I'm trying to understand how this works.

---

****Update:****

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  namespace: default  
spec:  
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  replicas: 2  
  template:  
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: site
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30001
```

Again, when I use the k8s CLI, I'm able to see my deployment, yet when I hit `localhost:30001`, I get an `Unable to connect` message.

Comment: Please teach me about your Kubernetes environment.  
(e.g. GKE, Docker Desktop, etc...)

Because the way to access your app depends on the Kubernetes environment.

And please show me all the yaml files you applied.
For example, reach-deployment yaml is not found in your question.
If I don't know the state of you configured, I can't exactly answer your question.

Comment: @bells17 sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given `containerPort: 80` but if your app listens on port `8080` change it to `8080`.

There are different ways to access an application deployed on kubernetes

1. [Port Forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) using `kubectl port-forward deployment/my-deployment 8080:8080`
2. [Creare a NodePort service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) and use `http://<NODEIP>:<NODEPORT>`
3. [Create a LoadBalanceer service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/). This works only in supported cloud environment such as AWS, GKE etc.
4. [Use ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) such nginx to expose the application.

Comment: even if i change it to 8080, when I go to localhost:8080 it doesn't work.

Comment: Is any one of these considered more conventional? My goal is to deploy my application in a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Port forward is easiest for development purpose...you dont need to create a service for that.but port forward does not work in a real production system

Answer (score 0):

By Default k8s application are exposed only within the cluster, if you want to access it from outside of the cluster then you can select any of the below options:

1. Expose Deployment as a node port service (**kubectl expose deployment my-deployment --name=my-deployment-service --type=NodePort**), describe the service and get the node port assigned to it (**kubectl describe svc my-deployment-service**). Then try **http://<node-IP:node-port>/**
2. For production grade cluster the best practice is to use LoadBalancer type (**kubectl expose deployment my-deployment --name=my-deployment-service --type=LoadBalancer --target-port=8080**) as part of this service you get an external IP which can be used to access your service **http://EXTERNAL-IP:8080/**

You can also see the details about the endpoint using **kubectl get ep**

Thanks,